# Does the Girvan–Newman community detection algorithm work on a weighted graph with non-integer weights?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, igraph

I have a weighted undirected graph, where weight is distance and it is between 0 and 1. I want to apply the weighted version of [Girvan–Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm) community detection.

I think weight must refer to strength or similarity, so if I convert the distance to similarity (e.g., 1 - distance), can I apply the algorithm? or must the weight be an integer also?

Answer (score 1):

Newman's modularity works for undirected weighted networks. You do not need to do anything to your edge weights. Modularity is given by:

$$Q = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{ij}\left[A_{ij}- \frac{k_ik_j}{2m}\right]\ \delta(c_i,c_j) $$

where in an ***unweighted*** network, $m$ is the number of edges in the network, $A_{ij}$ is 1 if $i$ and $j$ share an edge and 0 otherwise, $k_i$ is the degree of vertex $i$, and $\delta(c_i,c_j)$ is 1 if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise. In a ***weighted*** network, binary values are simply replaced by edge weights, so $m$ is the sum of all edge weights in the network, $A_{ij}$ is the edge weight between vertices $i$ and $j$, $k_i$ is the strength of vertex $i$, and $\delta(c_i,c_j)$ remains the same.

For more, see [this paper by Newman](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.70.056131) on analyzing weighted networks.